# c to c++, lost in translation

Tags: c++, c, port

I am attempting to convert a tool from C to C++ so I can compile as a CLR.  I am a .NET guy so this is well outside my comfort zone.

I have a compile error on the following line (tell me if this is not enough information):

```
if (qvartype[ currQ ] == FLOATING )
    *range *= get_scale( currQ );             /* Make range units match  */
                                              /* data units.             */
```

`currQ` is a `short`.  The error is defined on the `get_scale` function.  This function is defined earlier as:

```
#define get_scale( i ) ((short)pow( 10, (int)((long)(cat_names[ i ]))))
```

...which looks ridiculous to me, deep into type casting hell, but it does compile in C.  However, in C++, I get the following error message:

```
Error   374 error C2668: 'pow' : ambiguous call to overloaded function
```

I understand C does not employ the concept of overloads, but C++ does, and the variable signature on this hot mess makes it unclear which function to invoke.

How do I fix this?  What would be the right way to write this for maximum compatibility with C++?

Comment: Minor note, `get_scale` is not a function, it's a macro.

Comment: The set of overloads may also be different depending on whether you `#include <math.h>` or `#include <cmath>` or both, whether you `using namespace std;` (not recommended) and also depends on the toolchain.  It really is pretty ugly.  The easiest thing to do is make the types match the C `pow()` function, so the C function is always chosen.

Comment: If your powers of 10 that you need to compute fit into an integer (and it looks like that's what you're doing), it may be faster just to use a static lookup table instead of calling `pow`.  I would do that anyway, as there are some implementations of `pow` that have slight rounding errors, even if you're using integers.

Comment: Upvoted for the movie reference alone.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I expect there's a lot of things I could do to this code to make it work much better, but I'll settle for having it build.

Comment: One is tempted to replace the scaling array `cat_names` with a simple `long` array containing the correct values for the powers of 10, just to remove this entire ghastly construction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no overloaded version of pow() in C++ which satisfies your calling signature of `(int, int)`. One of the supported calling conventions is `(double, int)` so modifying your call to:

```
pow(10.0, ...)
```

should be enough

Comment: shouldnt `  double pow (Type1 base      , Type2 exponent); ` fit into the (int,int) signature?

Comment: @thermite: that's a C++11 extension.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs Using floating point to perform integer operations runs the risk of rounding errors, so it would be an improvement to replace this macro with an inline function that actually does integer multiplication

Comment: @MattMcNabb Thanks, I'll mark that as a "todo"... first step is to get this bundle of joy to build...

Comment: Might depend a bit on what the type of the variable pointed to by `range` is.

Answer (score 0):

in c++ the pow function has the following signature

```
double pow (double base, double exponent);
```

so if you made you call something like

```
#define get_scale( i ) ((short)pow( 10.0, (double)cat_names[ i ])))
```

but that is using a macro, and i'm not too comfortable with those. i would create a function

```
short get_scale(int i){return (short)pow( 10.0, (double)cat_names[ i ])};
```

see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/pow/

Comment: That's one of the signatures.

Comment: [It has many overloads](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow) otherwise OP wouldn't be getting an `ambiguous call to overloaded function` error.

Comment: My bad when i went to cplusplus.com it was in the c90 documentation by default, which only had 1 signature but you are right. however changing to be doubles only would work.

Answer (score 0):

According to

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dt5dakze.aspx

there are many `pow()` variants. You're calling `pow()` with type casting, but the compiler has few functions matching and gets confused.

Change the definition of `get_scale()` to be more specific about types, so the compiler can select proper `pow()` version unambiguously.